# Can i use $rootScope inside a factory?

Tags: angularjs

I have a function inside a factory that needs to set a variable to `true` on the `$rootScope`. How would I apply this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is this related to Cordova? Please, be more specific.

Answer (score 26):

Inject `$rootscope` dependency in the factory's function constructor and use it.

```
module.factory( 'factoryName', function($rootScope){
    $rootScope.value = "value";
});
```

EDIT:

If I understood corectly, this is how you use it from the service's return statement:

```
module.factory('ModifyRootScopeService', function($rootScope){

   return {
       setRootScopeValue: function(value){
            $rootScope.value = value;
       }
   }
});
```

Then, whenever you use this service (after injecting it), call

```
ModifyRootScopeService.setRootScopeValue("true");
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but how would i apply this if was calling functions in return{}